# Redimensionar directorio /var en Linux sin Gparted

Tags: linux, proceso, debian-9

La redimensión del directorio /var la logré con el live CD de Gparted por la urgencia que tenía en ejecutar el proceso, sin embargo, mientras esperaba por el .iso del Gparted se me ocurrió intentar redimensionar la partición "en vivo". Para completar esta tarea leí que debía desmontar primero /var.

Sucede que intenté desmontar /var pero el sistema me arrojó un mensaje que decía (palabras mas, palabras menos) que había un proceso en ejecución en /var y al estar ocupada no podía realizarse el desmontaje.

Me encargué de investigar y no encontré una explicación concreta y convincente de por qué /var no se puede desmontar desde el mismo sistema operativo en el que está corriendo actualmente por lo que decidí intentarlo.

Reinicié la maquina (para no tener ningún proceso adicional que me impidiera ejecutar el proceso) y desmonté forzosamente /var a través de la terminal. La maquina en respuesta a mi acción generó un "pestañeo" visible en el monitor, aclaro que no fué reinicio del sistema porque cuando la pantalla encendió nuevamente no booteó sino que me pidió usuario y contraseña como si retornara de un estado de suspensión o hibernación.

> Entonces me quedaron dudas respecto a todo lo mencionado anteriormente. Estas dudas son:
>
> 1) Es posible redimensionar en "vivo" o en "caliente" /var?
>
> 2) Por qué mi maquina "pestañeó" al desmontar /var forzosamente?
>
> 3) Cuáles procesos maneja son lo suficientemente importantes como para que al
>   intentar desmontar /var el sistema me arrojé el mensaje que mencioné
>   anteriormente?
>
> 4) Por qué siendo tan importante a nivel de programación (entre otras cosas) la carpeta /var el sistema (Debian por ejemplo) en su proceso de instalación al realizar un particionado "guiado" le suministra un espacio tan infimo en comparación a la totalidad del disco? Hay algún motivo en especial para ello?

**Observación:** Sé que /var es referencia para ciertos servicios asociados al desarrollo web (Apache, docker, entre otros) pero no creo que sean los que generan este problema ya que no hay "resistencia" del sistema al detener estos servicios por terminal.

**Observación 2:** He leído muchos foros y sitios de tecnología pero no explican a ciencia cierta un por qué convincente a cada una de las dudas planteadas y soy de los que le gusta entender lo mejor posible cada proceso, herramienta, etc.

Agradezco de antemano toda ayuda suministrada.

Comment: la jerarquía de archivos debian sigue el estándar FHS ver: http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s02.html y no tan completo pero en español https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: Gracias por las referencias me ha aclarado algunas cosas aunque me gustaría saber exactamente que genera el pestañeo del sistema al desmontar /var.

Comment: je imposible saber sin tener un listado de procesos corriendo pero digamos que el sistema tuvo un ACV y se recuperó como pudo (hay locks de dispositivos en uso en `/var/lock`, tal vez la pantalla pasó de multi proceso a mono proceso, pero es mas un "me parece a mi")

Comment: =P si el `/var/log` estuviera disponible al desmontar `/var` tal vez podrías ver que procesos se apagaron y cuales se reiniciaron aunque puede que haya algo en `/usr/log` (varios procesos usan usr/log cuando var/log no esta disponible)

Comment: @aloMalbarez xD! me parece que /var/log no quedó vivo después del umount jaja! Pero tomaré en cuenta el comentario para ver si dejó algún rastro que pueda utilizar para saber lo que sucedió en lo que acceda nuevamente al sistema operativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comando lsof te puede ayudar, le pones el punto de montaje y te dice los procesos que están con ficheros abiertos.

A continuación un ejemplo de como utilizarlo:

```
[root@sa08 ~]# lsof /bbdds1b/datos 

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME mysqld  15393 mtsasr1b  cwd    DIR 253,26     4096        67 /bbdds1b/datos/databases mysqld  15393 mtsasr1b    3uW  REG 253,26 79691776        68 /bbdds1b/datos/databases/ibdata1 mysqld  15393 mtsasr1b    8uW  REG 253,26 50331648        69 /bbdds1b/datos/databases/ib_logfile0
```

Comment: Es bastante parecido a lo que sería el comando `ls`. Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Si respondes completamente a mi pregunta la marco como correcta, ya le dí +1 porque ha sido útil.

Comment: El comando lsoft te va a dar el nombre e id de todos los demonios que tienen algún fichero abierto. Si los matas todos seguro que puedes ampliarlo en caliente. Aunque hay veces que no se puede y no te queda mas remedio que hacerlo desde un livecd.  Si arrancas en modo single user lo puedes hacer mas fácilmente.  Yo iría matando procesos que aparezcan en el lsof y ya verás como ves al matarlo qué demonio es el que te da el "corte", yo creo que es algo que tenga que ver con las X.

Comment: No lo había pensado así, muchas gracias por tu aporte! He colocado tu respuesta como correcta pero por favor coloca tu comentario anterior como parte de la respuesta (actualizala con esta información)